# Origin must be supplied Error in random date generation in R

Tags: r, kaggle

I am creating a notebook in Kaggle with the R code I used in RStudio IDE on my desktop system but I encountered the folloing error, though it's not present in Rstudio:

```
Error in as.Date.numeric(runif(45764, as.Date("1942-02-01", origin = "1942-01-01"), : 'origin' must be supplied
Traceback:

1. as.Date.numeric(runif(45764, as.Date("1942-02-01", origin = "1942-01-01"), 
 .     as.Date("2023-10-01", origin = "1942-01-01")))
2. stop("'origin' must be supplied")
```

This is the code which I used to generate random dates in RStudio:

```r
#4. Generate 45764 random dates
set.seed(45001) #setting a seed to ensure the dates are reproducible
rd_dates <- as.Date.numeric(runif(45764, as.Date("1942-02-01", origin = "1942-01-01"), 
                                  as.Date("2023-10-01", origin = "1942-01-01"))) #generate the random dates
```

Please, kindly help.
Thanks

I am expecting a random date

Answer (score 2):

Try with `origin` as guided by the error message:

```r
as.Date(runif(45764, as.Date("1942-02-01"), as.Date("2023-10-01")), 
        origin = "1970-01-01")
```

`as.Date(<numeric>)` used to require `origin`, while it was changed [in R 4.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html#:%7E:text=as.POSIXct(%3Cnumeric%3E)%20and%20as.POSIXlt(.)%20(without%20specifying%20origin)%20now%20work.%20So%20does%20as.Date(%3Cnumeric%3E)) and origin now defaults to `"1970-01-01"`, Kaggle is still using R 4.0.5 . Also note that `origin` has no effect on `as.Date(<character>)`

When you are working with different R and R package versions, it often makes sense to check the documentation on that exact system, i.e. in this case check `?as.Date.numeric` in Kaggle instead of relying on the same on your local system or Google results.